# Vaadin customize menu-bar css

Tags: css, vaadin, styled-components

i added my theme as jar as described by the documentation.

now i want to add a menu-bar with a single entry for a user-menu.
But i have some trouble to create a custom css.

in the theme i import my base.css

```
@import url('./base.css');
@import url('lumo-css-framework/all-classes.css');
```

all styles are loaded, fine :)
then i add the shadow-tree css in my base.css

```css
/* working */
vaadin-menu-bar{
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: aqua;
}

/* not working */
vaadin-menu-bar-button{
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: red;
}

/* not working */
vaadin-menu-bar [part="menu-bar-button"]{
  background: yellow;
}
```

https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components

may be i did understand something wrong. Any help would great :)

Comment: If you use IE9, you can not stylize unknown elements.  If you use Chrome or Firefox or Safari or IE>9, it should work. If you want to stylize them, add script that uses `document.createElement` to create all of them. See http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#unknown-elements for more information.

Comment: using firefox 89.0.2 (64-bit) but it's not working :(

Comment: If you want to style a component you have to import the styles with CssImport and themeFor. Please checkout https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/importing-style-sheets

Answer (score 1):

so while using a JAR for the theme and the css belongs in

```
resource/META-INF/resources/themes/mytheme/base.css
```

i can use

```css
vaadin-menu-bar.usermenu::part(menu-bar-button){
  border-radius: var(--lumo-border-radius-m);
}
```

to set my custom style to the menubar with classname 'usermenu'